# Python, Arranging lists in list without using .sort()

Tags: python, list, sorting, merge

Lets say that

```
def arrange(Lists, type):
    '''your code'''
```

Given that:

```
Lists = [[['q', 'Leap Strike', 'Jax'],['w', 'Mocking shout', 'Tryndamere']],[['r', 'Ace in hole', 'Caitlyn']...[button, description, name]]]
```

Given also:

```
type can be button, description or name
```

Find:

```
arrange(Lists, name)
```

Expected Output:

```
[['r', 'Ace in hole', 'Caitlyn'],['q', 'Leap Strike', 'Jax'],['w', 'Mocking shout', 'Tryndamere']...]]
```

My approach:

```
def arrange(Lists, type):
    result = []
    for list in lists:
        result += list
```

Current ouput:

```
[['q', 'Leap Strike', 'Jax'],['w', 'Mocking shout', 'Tryndamere'],['r', 'Ace in hole', 'Caitlyn']...]]
```

Till here, I join all the lists into a new list. The next step is to sort the lists according to their type. How can I do that? Without using .sort or sorted

Comment: Homework alert!  Provide us more details so we that we could submit it on your behalf.

Comment: Can you please show examples of input/output?

Comment: What do you mean by "arrange"? What order should be produced?

Comment: Have you written a sorting function?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I hope after the edit it is clearer. Haha, this is my 1st post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_sort(a_list):
    changes_exist = True
    while changes_exist:
         changes_exist = False
         for i in range(len(a_list)-1):
             if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
                a_list = do_swap(a_list,i,i+1)
                changes_exist = True
    return a_list
```

is probably the simplest sorting algorithm  (replace do_swap with appropriate functionality ) and alter the search comparison to meet your specific needs

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter

def arrange(lst, column_name, columns=["number", "code", "name"]):
    item = columns.index(column_name)
    return sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(item))
```

which runs like

```
lst = [('C98124', 'book1', 'Shawn'), ('D12345', 'book2', 'James')]

arrange(lst, "name")
```

and returns

```
[('D12345', 'book2', 'James'), ('C98124', 'book1', 'Shawn')]
```

('James' before 'Shawn', as expected)

... replace `sorted` with an appropriate operation.